# Nunit Tests not showing in Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit

**Nunit Tests not showing in Visual Studio Test Explorer.!!**

Visual Studio 2015

I have installed NUnit 3.10.1 and NUnit Adapter 2.1.1 it did not worked.

**Solution:** Looks like both are not compatible.
I just uninstalled v3.10.1 and installed v2.6.4 with existing NUnit Adapter 2.1.1 it worked 

Answer (score 1):

As explained in all the documentation, the NUnit Visual Studio Adapter supports running NUnit 2.x tests under Visual Studio. The NUnit **3** Visual Studio adapter supports NUnit 3.0 and higher.

Even though it's first release was 3.0, the NUnit 3 adapter is a completely different product, not a just a version upgrade of the original adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as mentioned by Charlie, today tried with NUnit v3.10.1 and NUnit3TestAdapter v3.10.0.

Package.config should look like:

```
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.10.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```